# ¿Por que no me imprime el string sin las letras a,b,c?

Tags: javascript

// hola estoy tratando de pasarlo a array para ver si asi puedo sacar en una nuevo array los demas caracteres que no sean "a", "b" y "c", y asi poder cumplir con el ejercicio, pero nada .

```
function deleteAbc(cadena){
  //Define una función que elimine las letras "a", "b" y "c" de la cadena dada 
  //y devuelva la versión modificada o la misma cadena, en caso de contener dichas letras.
  //Escribe tu código aquí

  var a = [];
  var arr = cadena.split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if(cadena[i] !== "a"|| cadena[i] !== "b" || cadena[i] !== "c") {
     a.push(cadena[i])
     
    }
    
  }
 return a.toString();

}
```

Comment: Tienes que usar `and` en lugar de `or`. Pues buscas que la letra en un índice específico no sea ninguna de las tres.

Comment: Si usas OR, puedes tener la letra `a` pero como la `a` no es `b` ni `c`, entonces, la condición es verdadera. Y por lo tanto la letra no es ignorada.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera mas sencilla y mas limpia de hacerlo es con el replace, este metodo lo que hace es remplazar el caracter que le indiquemos en este caso por un campo vacio:

```
function deleteAbc(cadena){
  //Define una función que elimine las letras "a", "b" y "c" de la cadena dada 
  //y devuelva la versión modificada o la misma cadena, en caso de contener dichas letras.
  //Escribe tu código aquí
  return cadena.replace(/a/g,'').replace(/b/g,'').replace(/c/g,'');
}
```

Y el error en tu codigo es la logica de la condicion, ya que tiene que ser con el &&

```
function deleteAbc(cadena){
  //Define una función que elimine las letras "a", "b" y "c" de la cadena dada 
  //y devuelva la versión modificada o la misma cadena, en caso de contener dichas letras.
  //Escribe tu código aquí

  var a = [];
  var arr = cadena.split('');
  console.log(arr)
  for (var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if(cadena[i] !== "a"&& cadena[i] !== "b" && cadena[i] !== "c") {
     a.push(cadena[i])
    }
    
  }
 return a.toString();

}
```

Espero te haya ayudado amigo.

Comment: muchas gracias . uriel

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo sin usar `replace` sería usando el método [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) que toma una cadena y la separa de acuerdo al carácter separador que se pase como argumento, devolviendo un Array, y [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) que toma un Array y une cada elemento para formar una cadena, usando como caracter de unión el que se pasa como argumento.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function deleteAbc(cadena){
  return cadena.split('a').join('').split('b').join('').split('c').join('');
}

const cadenas = [
  'Hola',
  'abecedario',
  'calabazas',
  'abc123',
  'serio',
  '',
];

cadenas.forEach(c => {
  console.log(`${c} -> ${deleteAbc(c)}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteAbc(cadena) {
  //Define una función que elimine las letras "a", "b" y "c" de la cadena dada 
  //y devuelva la versión modificada o la misma cadena, en caso de contener dichas letras.
  //Escribe tu código aquí
  cadena = cadena.split('');
  cadena.forEach(function (key, index) {
    if (cadena[index] === "a" || cadena[index] === "b" || cadena[index] === "c") {
      delete cadena[index];
    }
  })
  return cadena.join('');
}
const str = "Hola jacqui my bb";
console.log(deleteAbc(str));
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? No está demás borrar el comentario "escribe tu código aquí", por cierto ;)

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de hacer la comparación solo debes agregar el caracter si el que se está recorriendo es diferente a los 3 que están dentro del if, aquí el error es que en lugar de utilizar el operador or **||** se debe utilizar el operador and **&&**, ya que se debe cumplir que el caracter  recorrido sea diferente a "a", "b" y "c", y solo si se cumplen todos los casos entrar al if, de otra manera te traerá todos los caracteres, porque siempre será diferente a alguno de ellos, por lo que el operador or || no sería adecuado para este caso.

Luego al final al devolverlo para que devuelva la cadena en un formato correcto habría que remover las comas del string.

Tu código funcionando quedaría así:

```js
function deleteAbc(cadena) {
  //Define una función que elimine las letras "a", "b" y "c" de la cadena dada
  //y devuelva la versión modificada o la misma cadena, en caso de contener dichas letras.
  //Escribe tu código aquí

  var a = [];
  var arr = cadena.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if ((cadena[i] !== "a" && cadena[i] !== "b") && cadena[i] !== "c") {
      a.push(cadena[i]);
    }
  }
  return a.toString().replaceAll(",", "");
}
```

---

Teniendo presente que los strings son iterables, se podría también hacer algo así:

```js
function deleteAbc(cadena) {
  //Define una función que elimine las letras "a", "b" y "c" de la cadena dada
  //y devuelva la versión modificada o la misma cadena, en caso de contener dichas letras.
  //Escribe tu código aquí

  var result = "";
  for (var caracter of cadena) {
    if (caracter !== "a" && caracter !== "b" && caracter !== "c") {
      result += caracter;
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

---

Por último otra forma de hacerlo es con un replace y una única expresión regular, quedando de esta manera:

```js
function deleteAbc(cadena) {
  //Define una función que elimine las letras "a", "b" y "c" de la cadena dada
  //y devuelva la versión modificada o la misma cadena, en caso de contener dichas letras.
  //Escribe tu código aquí
  return cadena.replace(/[abc]/gi, "")
}
```